# Decryption Queries and its meaning in identity-based encryption

Tags: identity-based-encryption, decryption-oracle

In identity-based encryption, for security proof, they sometimes describe random oracle for decryption queries. Therefore, I wonder decryption is handled by decryption oracle for all users? Users need help of decryption oracle for decryption?

Comment: You will get a lot of downvotes for this question as apparently you're missing  basics. The "oracle" is usually a concept or service with some function without specifying any implementation details. So maybe to get any reasonable answer, you have to rephrase your question or simply explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: [This Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/what-is-a-cryptographic-oracle) question covers the basics of oracles. Too bad it isn't here so this could be closed as a dupe.